# Bring a bootstrap col- up to the previous row at different breakpoint?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I've been through Bootstrap's documentation on the Grid - I might be missing something but i cannot see a way to do this.

I have a row with three columns (col-lg-4 for each) - i want to reorganise this to two columns at the col-md breakpoint (col-md-6), but i end up with empty space next to the third col- element (because the row contains three col- elements).

I have included an infographic to illustrate what i mean.

Is there a way (native to bootstrap) that will bring content from the next row up to fill this empty space?
[image: Reorganising basic bootstrap grid structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explaination is correct but it seems like your html structure does something wrong.

I have created a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/258711/) for you to show you one possible solution. Here is the running code:

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-lg-4 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.inside-col {
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 50px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="inside-col">
        col-md-4 col-lg-6
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="inside-col">
        col-md-4 col-lg-6
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="inside-col">
        col-md-4 col-lg-6
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="inside-col">
        col-md-4 col-lg-6
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="inside-col">
        col-md-4 col-lg-6
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="inside-col">
        col-md-4 col-lg-6
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I've misinterpreted correct usage for the row element, i think. My rows include only three col- elements, whereas your row encapsulates all of the col- elements and then marks up the CSS to control how they behave at different breakpoints, so they are all effectively inline and collapse according to the CSS identifiers. Many thanks!

Comment: Hm, this solution does work but it prevents me from adding background colour to individual rows with the container-fluid class in order to create horizontal banding.

Comment: This is in my opinion one of the biggest disadvantages in using bootstrap (it will also get interesting if columns have different heights). I would suggest to open a new question for this problem. The only idea I have is applying the style to something like `.col-lg-4:nth-child` (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) - so you could maybe manage to select single rows for large devices. And using `.col-md-6:nth-child` for medium devices.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm going to have to leave this for now.